# Background color gradient in Ionic 2

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

I'm trying to set the background-color for my app using `$background-color` variable in `variables.scss` file. This works fine when setting just a color, like `#000` or `#fff`, but can't make it work with a gradient.

`$background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #fff 100%);`

This code throws the following Sass error:

`argument '$color' of 'rgba($color, $alpha)' must be a color Backtrace`.

So, how can I set the background-color to be a gradient?

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm hitting the same issue myself...

Comment: No, unfortunately, I ended up using just one color instead of a gradient

Answer (score 3):

This is the `scss` code I use for my own background gradient.

```
$SIDEMENU_TOP: #A23C4B;
$SIDEMENU_BOTTOM: #ff9068;
$SIDEMENU_TRANSPARENCY: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);


.side-menu-gradient{
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, $SIDEMENU_TOP, $SIDEMENU_BOTTOM);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, $SIDEMENU_TOP, $SIDEMENU_BOTTOM);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, $SIDEMENU_TOP, $SIDEMENU_BOTTOM);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, $SIDEMENU_TOP, $SIDEMENU_BOTTOM);
}
```

*(Maybe highly inspired from [Ionic Creator - Creating beautiful Sidemenus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb0weT3vD6I&t=461s)* (YouTube)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the background colour of a page, for example `home.html` page, to a gradient, you should follow these two steps:

1. In `home.html` you should have a class called `home` in the `ion-content` tag:

   ```
   <ion-content padding class="home">
      ...
   </ion-content>
   ```

   Go to `home.scss` file (create one if you do not have it) and define the `home` class:

   ```
   .home {
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000 0%, #fff 100%);
   }
   ```
2. Make sure this sass is being compiled by importing it into `app.css` file:

   ```
   @import "../pages/home/home";
   ```

Insert this line of code in your `app.css` file.

Do `ionic run android` in your `Terminal` and ... you'll have a gradient background for your `home` page!

Done!

Answer (score 1):

`$background-color` variable won't work instead use `$app-background`

Example: 
`$app-background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #fff 100%);`